# How to draw optimal circle which covers all edges of polygon

Tags: java, math, algebra, geofencing

Can anyone help me to draw a circle using all edges of polygon , Since i am creating geofence in java for that i need to draw a circle outside polygon which covers all edges of polygon....

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share the result of your research.

Comment: @MrSmith42 i have code for polygon to find the point is inside or not , but i want to draw circle to enhance my code

Comment: Are you looking for the [smallest circle that encloses the polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem)?